# Strange behavior of Get-NetFirewallRule

Tags: powershell

I came across the fact that `Get-NetFirewallRule` cmdlet displays the parameters differently. For demonstration, I added "123.exe" to the firewall (Block Action). The cmdlet gives such a mapping of parameter values (for compactness of space, I have reduced some parameters):

```
$Rules = [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})
$Rules.Get = (Get-NetFirewallRule).Where({ $_.Action -in 'Block', 4 })
$Rules.Get

------------
DisplayName           : 123
DisplayGroup          : 
Group                 : 
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Domain, Private, Public
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Outbound
Action                : Block
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
```

Then, for the experiment, I placed the cmdlet in a different space and got a completely different display of parameters, which now has no Profile (I see the Profiles instead and the number 7 as the value):

```
$Rules = [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})
$RS = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace(); $RS.Open()
$RS.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Rules', $Rules)
$PS = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({

    $Rules.Get = (Get-NetFirewallRule).Where({ $_.Action -in 'Block', 4 })
})
$PS.Runspace = $RS
$Null = $PS.Invoke()
$Rules.Get

------------
Action                  : 4
Direction               : 2
DisplayGroup            : 
DisplayName             : 123
EdgeTraversalPolicy     : 0
EnforcementStatus       : {0}
LocalOnlyMapping        : False
LooseSourceMapping      : False
Platforms               : {}
PolicyStoreSource       : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType   : 1
PrimaryStatus           : 1
Profiles                : 7
```

Well, I added `-All`. I got again a convenient display of information:

```
$Rules = [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})
$RS = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace(); $RS.Open()
$RS.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Rules', $Rules)
$PS = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({

    $Rules.Get = (Get-NetFirewallRule -All).Where({ $_.Action -in 'Block', 4 })
})
$PS.Runspace = $RS
$Null = $PS.Invoke()
$Rules.Get

------------
DisplayName           : 123
DisplayGroup          : 
Group                 : 
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Domain, Private, Public
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Outbound
Action                : Block
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
```

I closed PowerShell ISE and reopened. I entered the same script and got what I expected. I got the numbers again as values:

```
$Rules = [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})
$RS = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace(); $RS.Open()
$RS.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Rules', $Rules)
$PS = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({

    $Rules.Get = (Get-NetFirewallRule -All).Where({ $_.Action -in 'Block', 4 })
})
$PS.Runspace = $RS
$Null = $PS.Invoke()
$Rules.Get

------------
Action                  : 4
Direction               : 2
DisplayGroup            : 
DisplayName             : 123
EdgeTraversalPolicy     : 0
EnforcementStatus       : {0}
LocalOnlyMapping        : False
LooseSourceMapping      : False
Platforms               : {}
PolicyStoreSource       : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType   : 1
PrimaryStatus           : 1
Profiles                : 7
```

**Question: how to always get such a display of parameters?**

```
------------
DisplayName           : 123
DisplayGroup          : 
Group                 : 
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Domain, Private, Public
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Outbound
Action                : Block
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you modify your call to Get-NetFirewallRule to include Select the properties you are looking for, it will get you the data you need.

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -All | select DisplayName, DisplayGroup, Group, Enabled, Profile, platform, direction, action, edgetraversalpolicy, looseSourceMapping, localonlymapping
```

You can pipe it to `format-table` if you are looking to generate a table like view, or `Out-GridView` for form like display.

```
$Rules = [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})
$RS = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace(); $RS.Open()
$RS.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Rules', $Rules)
$PS = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({

    $Rules.Get = (Get-NetFirewallRule -All | select DisplayName, DisplayGroup, Group, Enabled, Profile, platform, direction, action, edgetraversalpolicy, looseSourceMapping, localonlymapping) | ? { $_.Action -in 'Block', 4 }

})
$PS.Runspace = $RS
$Null = $PS.Invoke()
$Rules.Get
```

Comment: I would like to add that to find the properties use `Get-NetFirewallRule | Get-Member`.

Comment: Correct. These are only some of the properties that OP showed interest in but to get the full list of properties, `| get-member` will provide them.